# Excel Formula to find a specific number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

A newbie here, can someone help me to figure it out. I have the follwoing data in Excel:

Column A:

```
T1
T2
T3
2T1
3T2
1T3
```

I want to return how often T1 occurs in column A.. T1 in column A should be 3 (T1 + 2T1)

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly multiple ways, one way would be:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUM(IF(MID(A$1:A$6,SEARCH("T",A$1:A$6),LEN(A$1:A$6))=B2,IFERROR(LEFT(A$1:A$6,SEARCH("T",A$1:A$6)-1)*1,1),0))
```

***Note:*** Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: sorry another question to add...how about if in column A have another Variable for example A1, B1, 2B2 etc... i try with your formula and somehow not working. can you explain the formula? and how to solve this. thanks

Comment: @Laure, new questions do get new topics on SO. Instead of going back and forth I think it's best to create a new question where you can show your sample values and expected results. Sounds to me like you have a bunch of "special" characters instead of just the "T" to look out for.

Comment: Ok i will post a new question

Comment: i post a new question.[Link new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61655039/excel-formula-to-find-a-specific-number-in-variant-variable)