# Excel formula to find a specific number in variant variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following

[image]

how can i get the sum number from T1 example or A1?

The Variable in Column A can be variant.

Result in C2 should count how many T1 in Column A or how many A1 in Column A and so on for other Values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: i dont ask someone to write a code. i got help from someone and he need detail from my question before.

Comment: I have answered the question below, but I agree with @eirikdaude. I asked you to post a new question, not just for me but for the community. Rules on how to formulate a question still apply. See [ask] as question with a [mcve] and please for future question try to apply these simply basic rules. Your own attempt is very much appreciated, no matter how bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following array formula:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(C1,RIGHT($A$1:$A$12,LEN(C1)))*((SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$12,C1,""))),0))+COUNTIF($A$1:$A$12,C1)
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61652190/9758194) older question I believe you could try the following:

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61652190/9758194]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=SUM((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&B2,A$1:A$12)))*(IFERROR(LEFT(A$1:A$12,SEARCH(B2,A$1:A$12)-1)*1,1)))
```

Beware that this answer is applicable to the sample data provided but will fail when you start having data as `T11` etc. However, you haven't provided any further information so hopefully this will do.

---

A much more solid solution could be to use some `XPATH`:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",1,A$1:A$12)&"</s></t>","//s[substring(., string-length(.)-"&LEN(B2)-1&")='"&B2&"']"),B2,"")*1,1))
```

***Note:*** Confirm both options through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try below formula and see if it helps.

`=SUMPRODUCT(IF(RIGHT($A$1:$A$12,LEN(B2))=B2,LEFT("0"&$A$1:$A$12,LEN($A$1:$A$12)+1-LEN(B2))+($A$1:$A$12=B2),0))`

Copy down as much needed.